# how many new array to be born when i connect tow array in php

Tags: php

I have two arrays. The first array is

```
Array_A = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

and the second array is

```
array_B = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Now I want to count how many new arrays consisting of 6 words are created from combining two arrays array_A, array_b, provided that 6 quarters in each of these new arrays do not overlap.
for example the newly created array

```
array1 = [a0, b1, c2, d3, e4, f5]
array2 = [a0, b2, c1, d4, e5, f2]
array3 = [a0, b3, c2, d5, e4, f1] 
.
.
etc.
```

I want to count how many arrays like this are generated

Comment: how to create new array by change position element in array java     Array_A = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
    and new array to created such as : 
    Array_A1 = [b, a, c, d, e, f]
    Array_A2 = [c, a, b, d, e, f]
    Array_A3 = [b, d, c, a, e, f]
    ....

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  All question details should be added to the question as an edit (not written as a comment under the question).  Your question does not show any evidence of research or effort -- for this reason, your question is receiving downvotes.  "Requirements dumps" are a form of abuse on the volunteers in this community -- we are not meant to be used as a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

By considering that both the arrays have same count like 6 in above exmaple :

case 1: If we want the Array_A (or any one array) elements to be first always
The total number combinations would be (count)!
As the count is 6 in our scenario, the total combinations are 6! = **720 combinations**

case 2: If the first element of combination can be from any array like a0 or 0a
The total number of combinations would be (count)! * 2
As the count is 6 in our scenario, the total combinations are 6! * 2 = 720 * 2 = **1440 combinations**
example arrays : [a0,b1,c2,d3,e4,f5] or [0a,1b,2c,3d,4e,5f].

Note : ! - is a factorial symbol, Where `n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)......3*2*1`

PHP code to print all the arrays that can be formed

```
<?

$arrayB = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$arrayBPermutations = permutationsOfAnArray($arrayB);
$combinedArray = array();
$arrayA = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayBPermutations); $i++) {
   for ($j = 0; $j < count($arrayA); $j++) {
      ${'combinedArray' . $i}[$j] = $arrayA[$j] . $arrayBPermutations[$i][$j];
   }
}
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayBPermutations); $i++) {
   if ($i > 0 && ${'combinedArray' . $i} == ${'combinedArray' . ($i - 1)}) {
      error_log("found duplicate", 3, "/var/log/app/duplicates.log");
   }
   print_r(${'combinedArray' . $i});
}

//Swap Values
function swap(&$arr, $a, $b)
{
   $temp = $arr[$a];
   $arr[$a] = $arr[$b];
   $arr[$b] = $temp;
}

//Find Factorial of $n
function factorial($n)
{
   $val = 1;
   for ($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++) {
      $val *= $i;
   }
   return $val;
}

/**
 * All permutations of $arrayToPermutate
 * @param $arrayToPermutate
 * @return array
 */
function permutationsOfAnArray($arrayToPermutate)
{
   $total = factorial(count($arrayToPermutate));
   $count = 0;
   $arrayWithAllPerm = array();
   $arrPermIndex = 0;
   for ($j = 0, $i = 0, $inc = 1; $j < $total; $j++, $inc *= -1, $i += $inc) {

      for (; $i < count($arrayToPermutate) - 1 && $i >= 0; $i += $inc) {
         //store permutation in an array
         $arrayWithAllPerm[$arrPermIndex] = $arrayToPermutate;
         $arrPermIndex++;
         swap($arrayToPermutate, $i, $i + 1);
         $count++;
      }
      //store permutation in an array
      $arrayWithAllPerm[$arrPermIndex] = $arrayToPermutate;
      $arrPermIndex++;
      $count++;

      if ($inc === 1) {
         swap($arrayToPermutate, 0, 1);
      } else {
         swap($arrayToPermutate, count($arrayToPermutate) - 1, count($arrayToPermutate) - 2);
      }
   }
   //print total permutations
   echo "Total count of permutaions is " . $count;
   return $arrayWithAllPerm;
}

?>
```

We can verify "/var/log/app/duplicates.log" file to check if the script is creating an duplicate arrays.

"Total count of permutaions is" printed to check the total count.

If we want to store all permutations of one array like arrayB =  array('a','b','c','d','e'), use below code.

```
<?

$arrayB = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$arrayBPermutations = permutationsOfAnArray($arrayB);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayBPermutations); $i++) {
   ${'a' . $i} = $arrayBPermutations[$i];
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayBPermutations); $i++) {
   if ($i > 0 && ${'a' . $i} == ${'a' . ($i - 1)}) {
      error_log("found duplicate", 3, "/var/log/app/duplicates.log");
   }
   print_r(${'a' . $i});
}

//Swap Values
function swap(&$arr, $a, $b)
{
   $temp = $arr[$a];
   $arr[$a] = $arr[$b];
   $arr[$b] = $temp;
}

//Find Factorial of $n
function factorial($n)
{
   $val = 1;
   for ($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++) {
      $val *= $i;
   }
   return $val;
}

/**
 * All permutations of $arrayToPermutate
 * @param $arrayToPermutate
 * @return array
 */
function permutationsOfAnArray($arrayToPermutate)
{
   $total = factorial(count($arrayToPermutate));
   $count = 0;
   $arrayWithAllPerm = array();
   $arrPermIndex = 0;
   for ($j = 0, $i = 0, $inc = 1; $j < $total; $j++, $inc *= -1, $i += $inc) {

      for (; $i < count($arrayToPermutate) - 1 && $i >= 0; $i += $inc) {
         //store permutation in an array
         $arrayWithAllPerm[$arrPermIndex] = $arrayToPermutate;
         $arrPermIndex++;
         swap($arrayToPermutate, $i, $i + 1);
         $count++;
      }
      //store permutation in an array
      $arrayWithAllPerm[$arrPermIndex] = $arrayToPermutate;
      $arrPermIndex++;
      $count++;

      if ($inc === 1) {
         swap($arrayToPermutate, 0, 1);
      } else {
         swap($arrayToPermutate, count($arrayToPermutate) - 1, count($arrayToPermutate) - 2);
      }
   }
   //print total permutations
   echo "Total count of permutaions is " . $count;
   return $arrayWithAllPerm;
}

?>
```

All the permutations are stored in $a0, $a1, $a2,...... variables.

Comment: i known 6!  =  720, please help me, how to write code php function, i wanna to write but i dont cant write it, thank you very much

Comment: Hi, Do you want to write code to find out the factorial or to create array with combination ?

Comment: i want to write code to find out  to create array with combination , mean i want to get result array, i understand 6! = 720 , but i want to write code to create new array combination. please help me, code php or android .thanks

Comment: I have updated my comment with required code to print all the combinations, Thank you.

Comment: my mean how to change position element in array $a = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
after change postion it will created new many array
such as : 
    $a1 = array('b','a','c','d','e','f');
    $a2 = array('c','b','c','d','e','f');
    $a3 = array('d','b','c','d','e','f');
    ...

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly, check the second code segment to store all the permutations of $a = array('a','b','c','d','e','f')

Comment: please help me convert this code to java code, thank very much.